# How to install Cocopods for flutter on Mac Monterery?

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio, rubygems

Trying to run a flutter application in Mac Simulator aslo on physical iphone but unable to install Cocopods on my mac. getting the while installing with this command `sudo gem install cocopods`

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...

ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/ext/ffi_c
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I 
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r 
./siteconf20230819-1935-vrwho2.rb extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    -- 
ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-ffi_c-dir
    --without-ffi_c-dir
    --with-ffi_c-include
    --without-ffi_c-include=${ffi_c-dir}/include
    --with-ffi_c-lib
    --without-ffi_c-lib=${ffi_c-dir}/lib
    --enable-system-libffi
    --disable-system-libffi
    --with-libffi-config
    --without-libffi-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
```

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:467:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError) You have to install development tools first. from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:546:in` block in try_link0'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tmpdir.rb:93:in `mktmpdir' from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:543:in` try_link0'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:570:in `try_link' from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:672:in` try_ldflags'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1832:in `pkg_config' from extconf.rb:9:in` system_libffi_usable?'
from extconf.rb:42:in `'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-21/2.6.0/ffi-1.15.5/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-21/2.6.0/ffi-
1.15.5/gem_make.out

So, I have installed the cocopods with brew and still getting the error.

```
 `Error output from CocoaPods:
  ↳
    WARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.
    Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:

    export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
    
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2_1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/unicode_normalize/normalize.rb:141:in `normalize': Unicode Normalization not appropriate for ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
    from /Users/tusharrai/.gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `unicode_normalize'
    from /Users/tusharrai/.gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `installation_root'
    from /Users/tusharrai/.gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:226:in `podfile_path'
    from /Users/tusharrai/.gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:105:in `markdown_podfile'
    from /Users/tusharrai/.gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:30:in `report'
    from /Users/tusharrai/.gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:66:in `report_error'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:396:in `handle_exception'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:337:in `rescue in run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:324:in `run'
    from /Users/tusharrai/.gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    from /Users/tusharrai/.gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `load'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2_1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/unicode_normalize/normalize.rb:141:in `normalize': Unicode Normalization not appropriate for ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
    from /Users/tusharrai/.gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `unicode_normalize'
    from /Users/tusharrai/.gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `installation_root'
    from /Users/tusharrai/.gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:226:in `podfile_path'
    from /Users/tusharrai/.gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:205:in `podfile'
    from /Users/tusharrai/.gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:160:in `verify_podfile_exists!'
    from /Users/tusharrai/.gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:46:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    from /Users/tusharrai/.gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    from /Users/tusharrai/.gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `load'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'
```

Exception: Error running pod install`

.profile File

export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

## Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH

variable change.
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source
"$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

## Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*

export PATH="$PATH:/Users/tusharrai/Development/flutter/bin"

eval "$(/usr/local/bin/brew shellenv)"
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/tusharrai/.gem/ruby/3.2.0/bin"

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source
"$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

## Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*

export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/ruby/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/ruby/include"
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
export PATH="/usr/local/bin/brew:$PATH"if which rbenv >
/dev/null;
then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi